# compile tor on centos6. Problems with libevent

Tags: c, compilation, tor, libevent

i have clean centos6 system, try to compile tor from sources.
1st way (installing libevent by yum). I do:

```
yum install libevent2
yum install libevent2-devel

...

(inside tor folder): ./configure
make
```

and get error:

```
src/common/libor-event.a(compat_libevent.o): In function `tor_gettimeofday_cache_clear':
/root/tor-0.3.1.7/src/common/compat_libevent.c:250: undefined reference to `event_base_update_cache_time'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [src/or/tor] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/tor-0.3.1.7'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

2nd way (installing libevent from sources).

```
yum remove libevent2
yum remove libevent2-devel
..
(from libevent folder): ./configure
make
make install
..
(from tor folder): ./configure
```

and get error:

```
checking whether we need extra options to link libevent... configure: error: Found linkable libevent in (system), but it does not seem to run, even with -R. Maybe specify another using --with-libevent-dir}
```

So, what am i doing wrong?) what to do next?

Comment: os exact version: Linux version 2.6.32-696.13.2.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c1bl.rdu2.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18) (GCC) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that you missed to add the libevent library to library options

```
LDFLAGS+=-L[path of the libevent.so] -levent
```

What is the output of the make?

Comment: you mean add it while configure tor? it doesn't support it. but it support --with-libevent-dir. It helps with configure, but make still shows error. Output is here: https://pastebin.com/EmLNaVUL

Comment: In that case you should check the config.log, what library flag is set.
And what is happening while checking the eventlog.
And the `make V=1` provides more information about what kind of commands are executed

Comment: Heh, it was too difficult)). I installed ubuntu and compiled there without any problems... Centos  is evil))